# iconv "incomplete character or shift sequence at end of buffer" error

Tags: shell, csv, iconv

I imports data from another server. Then my script converts it to .txt.

.csv file which i imported: dddd-cccc bbbbbb aaaa xx List_2015_10_27.csv

iconv command:

```
iconv -f UCS-2 -t UTF-8 /thepath/*List_2015_10_27.csv > /thepath/newfile.txt
```

It was working perfectly until yesterday. Now I have this error:

```
iconv: incomplete character or shift sequence at end of buffer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use iconv with -c option.

I should have one or more characters incompatible with your input charset "UCS-2"